# Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting after changing the database location

Tags: java, neo4j

I have used batch-importer to migrate the data from mysql to neo4j.

I'm able to import nodes and relationships to ne04j using batch-importer using the below command:

```
java -server -Xms1024M -jar D:/Neo4j/target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar     
neo4j/data/graph.db nodes.csv relationships.csv
```

After importing , when i started the neo4j server with database location changed(new location is pointing to the `neo4j/data/graph.db` created using batch-importer), the neo4j is not getting started and saying

```
Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,   
D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\graph.db
```

Also one of the file created under D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\graph.db is `messages.log` and content of that log file is as below:

```
2014-07-22 10:47:28.958+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Starting     
BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\new.graphdb])
2014-07-22 10:47:31.424+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Clean shutdown     
on BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\new.graphdb])
```

What's happening here?

So what needs to be done? How can I see the newly imported nodes and relationships in the neo4j server?

Comment: What's in your <neo4j install location\data\log files?

Comment: @luanne , there is no folder called as `data` under neo4j installation directory. But under newly created neo4j database there is one `messages.log` file and the file content is `2014-07-22 10:47:28.958+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Starting BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\new.graphdb])
2014-07-22 10:47:31.424+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Thread[main,5,main] Clean shutdown on BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[D:\Neo4j\data\neo4j\data\new.graphdb])`.

Comment: any updates on the above post?